# adding custom BarButtonItem to top navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Using the interface builder in my storyboard, I put a Bar Button Item in the top left corner of my navigation toolbar that toggles the edit view of my table view cells. I currently have the text something like "Edit cells"

My question is, how do I change this to use an image? I created my own custom image for Edit Cells on state and Edit Cells off state, but when I specify the image in the interface builder, the image is stretched in the bar button item. Do I need to make this bar button item programmatically from code to make it use the frame of the image? How do I specify state?

I feel there should be a way to do this in the interface builder but I tried to do this programmatically:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit-off.png"];
UIButton *showEditButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
showEditButton.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );
[showEditButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *showEditButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:showEditButton];
```

Now how do I add showEditButtonItem to the top left of the navigation bar?

[image]

actual image:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any screenshots?  When I set an image in IB it doesn't stretch it

Comment: see edit. its really the ordering i want to be able to edit, so I have the ordering icon there. notice it gets stretched in IB. is the image just too largE?

Comment: Hmm it looks like it is just being squashed, not stretched.  Try resizing the icon texture to match what a bar button item expects.  You can find all of the dimensions for varying icons in ios [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1)

Comment: Great!, worked. now for state, how do I swap out the image on click? I have another image for state on and off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons in iOS are expected to be of a certain size.  You can find all of the sizes of various icons you could want in the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1).

As for setting it to different icons for different states, I believe you need to do that in code.

To set the image for a `UIBarButtonItem` you just need to set the `image` property:

```
editButton.image = editActiveImage;
```

or

```
editButton.image = editInactiveImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

add the button programatically is something like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"kyyL4.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(editObject:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
```

put this code into `-viewDidLoad:` method of your **ViewController.m** file.

(the sad news is the image will be stretched in this way as well.)